# Contenido en navbar se desborda

Tags: bootstrap

este es mi problema: Tengo un navbar y al agregarle varios items, el contenido se desborda del navbar y termina generando un espacio en blanco para agregar el contenido que queda fuera del navbar, adjunto imagen del problema para mayor entendimiento:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto código del navbar:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary text-white" style="border-radius: 5px;">
        <a class="navbar-brand d-md-block d-lg-none">Categorías</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler active border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="fa fa-bars fa-lg text-white"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-left">
                @if (isset($categories) && $categories ?? '')
                @if($categories->count() <= 0) <!-- Si no existen categorias, se agregan categorias automaticas para no dejarlas en blanco -->
                    @if(isset($n_categories) && $n_categories ?? '')
                    @foreach ($n_categories as $categorietest)
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{$categorietest->categorie}}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="/?search={{$categorietest->categorie}}">Ver todos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="/?search={{$categorietest->subcategorie}}">{{$categorietest->subcategorie}}</a>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
                    </li>
                    @else
                    @foreach ($categories as $categorie)
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{$categorie->name}}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="/?search={{$categorie->name}}">Ver todos</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            @if ($categorie->subcategories ?? '' && $categorie->subcategories->count() < 0) @foreach ($categorie->subcategories as $subcategorie)
                                <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="/?search={{$subcategorie->name}}">{{$subcategorie->name}}</a>
                                @endforeach
                                @endif
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
                    @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es suficiente con añadir al nav-bar una clase `min-vw-100` la cual especifica que no quieres que el nav llegue a tener un ancho inferior al 100% de la pantalla como podrás ver en este ejemplo:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary min-vw-100">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 1
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 2
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 3
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 4
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 5
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 6
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 7
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 8
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 9
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 10
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 11
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 12
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 13
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Submenú 14
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--//navbar-collapse-->
    </div><!--//container fluid-->
</nav>
```

Pero si son muchos los submenús que tienes te recomiendo usar un navbar-collapse vertical para que la navegación por ellos sea más comoda, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<div class="collapse bg-primary" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
    <div class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow p-2">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Submenú 1
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow p-2">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Submenú 2
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item font-weight-bold" href="#">Ver todos</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a aria-label="Submenu" class="dropdown-item font-italic" href="#">_</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</div>
</nav>

<!-- Bootstrap javascript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!